# How To Change Base currency for a multi store site

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, currency, multicurrency, ce-1.9.2.4

How can I change the Base currency for a multi store site, currently I have a site with two store different currencies, and different payment gateway that requires the base currency to be set to this own country's base currency. But the Magento admin only allows me to set base currency on Default and does not give me the option to change the base currency on the other store.

How can I have base currency set according to store?

I am using Magento CE 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will paraphrase the answer of St0iK. You can't set different base currency per store, but you can do it per website. First you have to go to the **admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> CATALOG -> Catalog -> Price -> Catalog Price Scope** and change it **from Global to Website**. Now when you go to the **admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Currency Setup -> Currency Options** you can change Base Currency per Website, not only for Default (Global). So you have to transfer you stores to websites and you will be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that Base Currency can be set on each Store View. However, this option was not presented on the admin side. I had to change the system.xml

> app/code/core/Mage/Directory/etc/system.xml

```
<label>Base Currency</label>
```

I have to set the appropriate to change from 0 to 1

```
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

Once this was done, I could see Base Currency under "Currency Options" even within a store view. This now works well and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: this works best. hassle-free

Comment: Why isn't this default for Magento? There must be a reason right? Otherwise it would be nice to have it in the default package.

Comment: I just tested this, but it has unwanted results. When I change the price of a product in a storeview, it changes all prices of all storeviews.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set-up multiple websites, one for each currency (not just store views, complete websites)

Then you will be able to change the store from the Configuration scope dropdown in settings, and un-check the checkbox(Use website) on the currency.

Then you will be able to set different currencies for each of your stores.

[image]